# Adding a row to an existing datatable in JSF

Tags: jsf

I have a requirement of changing an existing JSF 1.1 project where I need to add an additional row to a datatable on click of a button. Currently the datatable loads 3 rows from the backing bean and this new button should add additional rows to the datatable on each click. Using the suggestion provided by http://balusc.blogspot.com/2006/06/using-datatables.html I was able to display the additional row on the UI but I could not save the new data back to the database because the backing bean is in request scope and I cannot change the scope of this bean as it would create other issues. Can somebody provide me a solution to display the new row and also to save the data back to the database when the backing bean is in request scope.

Thanks
Shyam

Answer (score 0):

> but I could not save the new data back to the database because the backing bean is in request scope

The linked article provides code examples how to do this in the request scope. If you fail in saving the new rows, then apparently the data (pre)loading logic is incorrect. I'd suggest to go through the article from the beginning.

Comment: Thanks BalusC and Hari.. your suggestions has been useful and finally I was able to get the required result